# Filtering pandas dataframe using ipywidgets

Tags: python, pandas, ipywidgets

I am using a dropdown widget for the values in one of the columns in my dataframe. Based on the value I choose in the dropdown, I want the dataframe to filter only those rows. I would then go on to use the filtered dataframe for my analysis.

```
col1 |  col2    |  col3
  A  |   Orange | 2
  B  |   Apple  | 3
  A  |   Apple  | 4
```

I would have a dropdown (using ipywidgets) for col2 and when I choose `Apple`, I want to get the resulting dataframe.

```
col1  | col2   | col3
  B   |  Apple | 3
  A   |  Apple | 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shows the fruit you select from the dropdown menu. I would advise you to watch the Scipy 2020 recoring on Interactive widgets if you want to learn more about widgets.

```
from ipywidgets import interact
import pandas as pd

def show_df(value):
    data = [['A', 'Orange', 2],['B', 'Apple', 3],['A', 'Apple', 4]]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Letter','Fruit','Number'])
    print(df[df.Fruit==value])

interact(show_df, value = ['Apple','Orange'])
```

There are more dedicated ways to create a dropdown menu but this works. Such as in this example:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
widgets.Select(
    options=['Linux', 'Windows', 'OSX'],
    value='OSX',
    # rows=10,
    description='OS:',
    disabled=False
)
```

Comment: Thank you! The second one is how I am doing it but that would just create a dropdown with values. I am looking for a way to tie that with the dataframe.

Comment: The first one was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ipywidgets specifically but assuming you can get the value of your selection, say "Apple", filtering out by column values is quite easy.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["A", "B", "A"],
               "col2": ["Orange", "Apple", "Apple"],
               "col3": [2, 3, 4]})

df = df[df["col2"] == "Apple"]
```

Then, when you print df, you will get

```
  col1   col2  col3
1    B  Apple     3
2    A  Apple     4
```

Basically you create a mask (a dataframe of True and False values) through `df["col2"] == "Apple"` and then you can use that mask as an index to only get the values where the mask is True.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at it from a widget aspect.